# fb login error in php

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am creating fb login with the php ,
the problem is that the email of user is not returning from facebook,
FBID and USER NAME is returning.

The same code i have done for another project is working but for the new one is not working

the code is like this

```
require 'src/facebook.php'; // Include facebook SDK file
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'XXXXXXXXXXX', // Facebook App ID
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // Facebook App Secret
    'cookie' => true,
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fbid = $user_profile['id']; // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbuname = $user_profile['username']; // To Get Facebook Username
        $fbfullname = $user_profile['name']; // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $user_profile['email']; // To Get Facebook email ID
        /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
        $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $fbuname;
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $femail;

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
if ($user) {
    header("location:fblogin.php");
} else {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'email', // Permissions to request from the user
    ));
    header("location: " . $loginUrl);
}
```

Comment: Please state a question :-) Click the EDIT link in the question to append the information.

Comment: The question which m asking is in first line @cindy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,email');
```

It´s called "Declarative Fields", see changelog. Btw, you can´t get the username anymore.